# Archiving old photos to Google Plus (off the phone, but accessible)

Tags: photos, google-plus-photos

I have an EyeFi in my camera. The client on my phone polls it and downloads new photos. My phone automagically backs them up to Google Plus Photos. So from taking a picture, I can access them from any browser or computer syncing my photos with G+. That's really handy.

But this takes up a **lot** of space on my phone (which has no SD card support). When I attempt to delete a photo from the Photos app, it tells me it's going to die *everywhere*.

I would like to "archive" my photos in such a way that:

- I can access them through Google Plus
- I can access them through my phone (in the Photos app)
- They aren't taking up space on my phone
- I don't have to delete them from "everywhere". I want a copy on G+ until I delete it from G+.

I have some photos from ~2006 in a Picasa web album that are automatically pulled into the Photos app. They aren't on my phone, but I can still see them. This is what I'm after.

How do I achieve this? And bonus points if I can batch this so every month I can run something to archive photos over 3 months old.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a built in gallery app or file explorer delete the photos (locally) on the device via one of these apps (if not install an app to-do so) and then they should stay in the cloud if auto-backup is enabled and ran before deleting them. 
This "should" work as it's worked with my phone... But I don't have a lot of experience with smart cameras...